# safe shift from xhtml to html5

Tags: html, css

Site pages declared as XHTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

is it safe to change it to HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

and is there any point in it considering that the project is quite large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it safe to change it to HTML5

So long as you are serving the document as `text/html`.

> and is there any point in it

Not unless you are updating the page anyway.